# Table not updating on C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I am trying to update a table to register the time that the visitor is leaving and the state of the visit.
I have a datagridview that with a selection of a cell it gets the info of the whole row and then gets de ID of the visitor and sets the leaving time and the state of the visitor.
Here is the check out method:

```
private void CheckOutButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int outId = 0;
            DateTime dT = (DateTime)selectRow.Cells[4].Value;
            try
            {
                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT PersonID as ID from Person where Name = @Name AND Surname = @Surname AND IdNumber = @IdNumber AND DocType = @DocType", connect))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    com.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = selectRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                    com.Parameters.Add("@Surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = selectRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    com.Parameters.Add("@DocType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = selectRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    com.Parameters.Add("@IdNumber", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = selectRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();

                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
                    r.Read();
                    outId = Int32.Parse(r["ID"].ToString());
                    r.Close();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show(outId.ToString());

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Visits SET Out = @Leaving , State = @State FROM Visits WHERE PersonID = @PersonID AND Out is NULL AND Entrance = @Entrance", connect))
                {
                    connect.Open();
                    command.Parameters.Add("@PersonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = outId;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Leaving", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@Entrance", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dT;
                    command.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;


                    string query = command.CommandText;

                    foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
                    {
                        query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
                    }
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlTransaction trans = connect.BeginTransaction();
                    trans.Commit();
                    connect.Close();
                }
                goodCheckOut.Visible = true;
                updateTable();
            }
            catch (SqlException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }
```

This is the table design:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visits](
   [PersonID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL,
   [Delivery] [bit] NOT NULL,
   [Entrance] [datetime] NOT NULL,
   [Out] [datetime] NULL,
   [WorkerId] [int] NOT NULL,
   [cardNumber] [int] NULL,
   [VisitingCompany] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
   [State] [bit] NULL,
   [Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
   [Comment] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   (
       [PersonID] ASC,
       [Entrance] ASC
   )
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is your actual issue? Is it throwing an exception?

Comment: I try to set the Out to current time and the State to true but it doesn't change a thing. No changes at all. I will edit the question to make it clear

Comment: Ok, so what debugging have you done? Have you run it in debug mode and checked that the parameter values are being bound using values which you expected? Are there definitely any matching rows in the database? If you run the query manually in SQL using the same values for the parameters as the C# code is using, does it work as intended?

Comment: I tried to run it to see if it was fetching the correct user ID and tried to alter values on the table but I don't know why, didn't try to run alter the things that I wanted

Comment: Remove "FROM Visits" in the SQL statement.

Comment: I found the error, the problem is actually in another place. When I add a new visitor it "duplicates" the information and always gets the one with the lower ID. So if I add the same person to a visit various times it only deletes once and then it does nothing. Thank you for all the tips and help

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong, so I suspect that would make it malfunction (or rather act in a different way than you are trying to achieve):

What you need is this (it updates all records matching a filter with provided values):

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [field assignment] WHERE [filter]
```

What you have is this

```
UPDATE [table1] SET [field assignment] FROM [table2] WHERE [filter]
```

This query type of query updates records of `table1` FROM records of `table2` that match the filter. **This type of query is not applicable in your case** and they generally have `1-to-1` or `1-to-many` relationship setup in where clause, to clearly indicate which records are being updated from which records.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on some other place.
While adding a new person I don't check correctly if the person is already added. So, that way, when trying to add a new visit it gets always the lower numbered person.

Thank you for all the tips and help provided.